# Linix Mint Live CD: DNS not working, but will ping out fine

Tags: linux, networking, security, internet, linux-mint

I am running the Linux Mint (Cinnamon) 64-bit Live CD with VirtualBox on my Windows 8.1 Host computer.
The guest can ping 63.84.3.27 (Google) just fine, but cannot access the web.

I tried changing the DNS from 'automatic' to 8.8.8.8, 8.8.6.6 and to the default gateway (10.0.2.2) but neither help.

`nslookup` fails

What should I do next?

```
mint@mint ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:35:ec:85 
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ao0:27ff:fe35:ec85/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:74 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:593 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2317887 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:71947 (71.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1411171017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1411171017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:119667293579 (119.6 GB) TX bytes:119667293579 (119.6 GB)
```

```
mint@mint ~ $ ping 63.84.3.27
PING 63.84.3.27 (63.84.3.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 63.84.3.27: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=119 ms
64 bytes from 63.84.3.27: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=116 ms
64 bytes from 63.84.3.27: icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=46.9 ms
^C
--- 63.84.3.27 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 46.921/94.103/119.048/33.382 ms
```

```
mint@mint ~ $ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
mint@mint ~ $ ip route show
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  proto static 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1
```

```
mint@mint ~ $ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Edit:

```
mint@mint ~ $ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
mint@mint ~ $ nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.23
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.24
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.27
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.25
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.26
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.22
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.21
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 63.84.3.20
```

```
mint@mint ~ $ sudo cat \etc\resolv.conf
cat: etcresolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

Comment: first does `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8` work? what DNS address should your DHCP server be pushing down? what do you get from `sudo cat \etc\resolv.conf`? how did you try to set the DNS server address? it is possible that your router expects you to use it for DNS resolution (masquerading), and is not letting DNS response traffic back to you.

Comment: I edited my post with the results of those commands. Also, I set the DNS by going to "Network settings > IPv4, setting "automatic" to "Off", and entering the addresses there. I then issued "sudo ifconfig eth0 down", "sudo ifconfig eth0 up". I'm afraid I don't know what you meant by that last part involving masquerading.

Comment: It means you router is pretending to offer you dns but is really forwarding your requests to another dns server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mint Servers were hacked, linked OS ISO was compromised!**

On Feb 20th, 2016: [Hackers made a modified Linux Mint ISO, with a backdoor in it, and managed to hack the Mint website to point to it.](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994)

Looks like I won the lottery! The compromised OS was made into a bot.
Obviously if you've downloaded Linux Mint from linuxmint.com between Feb 20-21, you need to check your MD5. Likely you will need to acquire a legit version.

I found a legit copy, and what do you know? The internet works fine now.